# How can I make a query for each month of each year in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a query that gets fields that corresponds that month for each month of each year

something like this:

```
                      field 1                                field 2 

       count_of_fields_that_corresponds_this_month, same_fields_but_with_value_true
       --------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
january                                            |
       --------------------------------------------|-------------------------------
february                                           |
       --------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
march                                              |
       --------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
april                                              |
       --------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
etc...                                             |
```

in this example i have 2 fields that i need to fill in the table, but in reality i have many more, but i don't know how to get that fields for each month in one query, i have tried to make the same thing but with many queries, and i think its a bad practice, so can you advice me how to do this? or what functions i need to use in mysql?

i want to take field1, field2, field3, etc.... for each month, and if is possible also for each year, thank you very much.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT count(*) AS count FROM `simple` WHERE `ochistka` = 'somevalue' AND MONTH(`date`) = 01");
$this->db->query("SELECT count(*) AS count FROM `simple` WHERE `ochistka` = 'somevalue' AND MONTH(`date`) = 01 AND `prime4anie` = 'somevalue'");
```

so in this queries i am getting that fields, but only for one month, how can i improve it and make them query for each month in one shot(query)?

Comment: oh i have maked a bad table for view, i don't know how to illustrate it, sorry :(, but i think you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: can you post some of the actual queries you wrote?

Comment: You are looking for crosstab or pivot query, in whatever version of mysql you have.

Comment: I suggest posting a create table statement that will show people what you are working with and then a simple example of the output you want from your query.

Comment: Also provide your table structure

Comment: i have added some code that i have wrote, its small

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield), COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2)
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield)
```

put your own field and table names

Comment: The SQL pattern is an aggregation - as long as you only group on YEAR and MONTH you can SUM, AVERAGE, MIN, MAX and COUNT other fields

Answer (score 0):

Remove the month portion of the query and you will get an array of results. Then you can add a group by call to sort them.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM `simple` WHERE `ochistka` = 'somevalue' GROUP BY MONTH
```